# Error: Storyboard references before ios 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode9.1

I upgraded my XCode to 9.1 and all of a sudden my project stopped compiling for Deployment Target 7.0 and start giving this error

Class unavailable: 'Storyboard references before ios 8.0'.

My app has to give support to iOS version 7.0 and above.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

a 'Storyboard Reference' was lying unused in one of the storyboards, i simply deleted it and it started to compile.